# Getting response in PHP multiprocessing

Tags: php, ajax

I'm using XAMPP PHP v8 on Windows.
I am sending multiple requests to the /process.php file with a script I prepared with Ajax.
process.php activates a long command line on Windows, but when I close any of the sub-processes from the task manager, it does not receive ajax response. Only after all the tasks are completed does the whole process.php suddenly respond. Is a solution possible to this?

Run.html

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "process.php",
    data: "cmd=ping",
}).done(function (data) {
    if (data.status == true) {
        alert("done");
    } else {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Process.php

```
function ff_Execute(){
    
    $descriptorspec = array(
       1 => array("pipe", "w")
    );

    while (@ ob_end_flush());

    $process = proc_open("ffmpeg.exe -i *******", $descriptorspec, $pipes);

    $pstats = proc_get_status($process);
    
    $pid = $pstats['pid'];
    
    if (is_resource($process)) {

        while (!feof($pipes[1])) {
           
           $hb_output = fgets($pipes[1], 90);

            @flush();
           
       }
       
       fclose($pipes[1]);

       $ret = proc_close($process);
       
    }
    
}
```

I send 5 queries at once and all of them are working but when I close any of them from task manager it waits for all of them to get an answer
I terminated ffmpeg from the task manager where it monitors traffic with Firefox, I have to wait for it to finish in other processes to get a response.

Comment: Please add "process.php" content to your question

Comment: @IvanBarayev yes added.